# Json response. Retrieve specific values with javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a API working in shopify and when I use the url of specific task, it gives back a response in JSON. The browser translate it in RAW. However, my question is how can I retrieve specific value from the JSON response? I want just the section "properties" to extract only, with a javascript or php script. The code below is not a file.json, it is a response from the server when I call a specific url. 
mysite.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?fields=line_items

Example of JSON response:

```
{
    orders: [50]
    0:  {
        name: "#1347"
        line_items: [1]
        0:  {
            fulfillment_service: "manual"
            fulfillment_status: null
            gift_card: false
            grams: 0
            id: 966685828
            price: "45.00"
            product_id: 455951420
            quantity: 1
            requires_shipping: true
            sku: ""
            taxable: true
            title: "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)"
            variant_id: 1292559264
            variant_title: ""
            vendor: null
            name: "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)"
            variant_inventory_management: null
            properties: [9]
            0:  {
                name: "Glove Size"
                value: "M"
            }-
            1:  {
                name: "Hat Size"
                value: "L/XL"
            }-
            2:  {
                name: "Pant Size"
                value: "30x30"
            }-
            3:  {
                name: "Right or Left Handed?"
                value: "Right"
            }-
            4:  {
                name: "Shirt Size"
                value: "M"
            }-
            5:  {
                name: "Shoe Size"
                value: "9"
            }-
            6:  {
                name: "shipping_interval_frequency"
                value: "1"
            }-
            7:  {
                name: "shipping_interval_unit_type"
                value: "Months"
            }-
            8:  {
                name: "subscription_id"
                value: "1522"
            }-
            -
            product_exists: true
            fulfillable_quantity: 1
            total_discount: "0.00"
            tax_lines: [0]
        }-
    -
    }
}
```

```js
1:  {
line_items: [1]
0:  {
fulfillment_service: "manual"
fulfillment_status: null
gift_card: false
grams: 0
id: 978288644
price: "45.00"
product_id: 449447992
quantity: 1
requires_shipping: true
sku: ""
taxable: true
title: "Loud and Wild Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)"
variant_id: 1253803928
variant_title: ""
vendor: null
name: "Loud and Wild Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)"
variant_inventory_management: null
properties: [9]
0:  {
name: "Glove Size"
value: "XL"
}-
1:  {
name: "Hat Size"
value: "L/XL"
}-
2:  {
name: "Pant Size"
value: "44x30"
}-
3:  {
name: "Right or Left Handed?"
value: "Left"
}-
4:  {
name: "Shirt Size"
value: "XXL"
}-
5:  {
name: "Shoe Size"
value: "10.5"
}-
6:  {
name: "shipping_interval_frequency"
value: "1"
}-
7:  {
name: "shipping_interval_unit_type"
value: "Months"
}-
8:  {
name: "subscription_id"
value: "1523"
}-
-
product_exists: true
fulfillable_quantity: 1
total_discount: "0.00"
tax_lines: [0]
}-
-
}-
2:  {...}-
3:  {
line_items: [1]
0:  {
fulfillment_service: "manual"
fulfillment_status: null
gift_card: false
grams: 0
id: 974181252
price: "45.00"
product_id: 455951420
quantity: 1
requires_shipping: true
sku: ""
taxable: true
title: "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)"
variant_id: 1292559264
variant_title: ""
vendor: null
name: "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)"
variant_inventory_management: null
properties: [9]
0:  {
name: "Glove Size"
value: "XL"
}-
1:  {
name: "Hat Size"
value: "L/XL"
}-
2:  {
name: "Pant Size"
value: "42x30"
}-
3:  {
name: "Right or Left Handed?"
value: "Right"
}-
4:  {
name: "Shirt Size"
value: "XXL"
}-
5:  {
name: "Shoe Size"
value: "12"
}-
6:  {
name: "shipping_interval_frequency"
value: "1"
}-
7:  {
name: "shipping_interval_unit_type"
value: "Months"
}-
8:  {
name: "subscription_id"
value: "1522"
}-
-
product_exists: true
fulfillable_quantity: 1
total_discount: "0.00"
tax_lines: [0]
}-
-
}
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Comment: Please post the actual JSON, not a decoded version. And indent it nicely with jsonlint.com so we can see the structure.

Comment: Yeah something's not right here, that isn't correct JSON syntax. When you say it's a response, do you mean that it appears in the DOM when you visit that url?

Comment: The "JSON" being displayed is most likely a browser JSON reader in firefox (built in) or chrome (Chome plugin: `Chrome JSON Viewer`). Useful when viewing a JSON response directly from an API

Comment: "shopify" has a developer site with lots of examples and also a forum for asking questions about their API ... just saying.

Comment: This is what the chrome plugin called "Advanced rest client application" displays after I make a GET request to the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `json_decode` if you want to use PHP

**PHP**

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

In your scenario:

```
$response = //your api response
$php_obj = json_decode($response);

//Print a specific order and specific items properties
var_dump($php_obj->orders[0]->line_items[0]->properties);

//Print the properties for each item in each order 
//(prefixed with the index of the order number and item number)
foreach ($php_obj->orders as $order_index => $order) {
   foreach ($order->line_items as $item_index => $item) {
     echo "order: {$order_index} item: {$item_index}";
     var_dump($item->properties);
   }
}
```

If you want to use JS

**PHP/JS**

```
<script>
  var response = "<?php echo $response; /*again your api response*/ ?>";
  var obj = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(obj.orders[0].line_items[0].properties)
</script>
```

Comment: I think he's already decoded it, that's how he got this structure.

Comment: Based on the output, it doesn't look like hes decoded it, it looks like how firefox desplays a json object.

Comment: Chrome will also display in that form if you have the "Chrome JSON Viewer" pluggin

Comment: That makes sense. His question also mentions Javascript, so you should also show how to do it with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: No problem, its actually quite nice

Comment: PHP uses `->` to access object properties, not `.`. And your PHP/JS isn't right at all, there's no `json.decode()` in JS.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been messing with php much lately

Comment: You need quotes around `<?php echo $response >?`

Comment: This is the answer whos getting me so close to the solution. 
Seth McCaline, what if I have more fields with the name properties 
How can I show all of them? The code under gives me only the first, but I have many others to show. Should I use a loop? How? 

var_dump($php_obj->orders[0]->line_items[0]->properties);

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I have a response with many values. The script of my question is only one part of it. 
I want to show all of them. The code you gave me just shows the first one. 

Please, arens1985 my skype

Comment: Do you have multiple api calls, or multiple objects that you want from one api call? Also which way did you end up going, the `php` or the `php/js` version?

Comment: I've updated my question. 
I call the API from URL, and it is a GET function. The response is all of the orders my shop have processed in shopify. There are more than 100 of orders that have many fields, one of the fields is the properties, that has some product options. I want just to show the properties field only. Your script shows me only the first order properties and nothing from my other orders

Comment: And are you using the `PHP` or the `PHP/JS` answer I gave you?

Comment: @SethMcClaine the PHP

Comment: @SethMcClaine 
You sir are my Hero :) 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

As people says in the comments, your response is not valid JSON.
The closest valid object to the one you posted will be formatted as this:

```
var response = {
orders: [50],
0:{
    name: "#1347",
    line_items: [1],
    0:{
        fulfillment_service: "manual",
        fulfillment_status: null,
        gift_card: false,
        grams: 0,
        id: 966685828,
        price: "45.00",
        product_id: 455951420,
        quantity: 1,
        requires_shipping: true,
        sku: "",
        taxable: true,
        title: "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)",
        variant_id: 1292559264,
        variant_title: "",
        vendor: null,
        name: "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)",
        variant_inventory_management: null,
        properties: [9],
        0:  {
            name: "Glove Size",
            value: "M"
        },
        1:  {
            name: "Hat Size",
            value: "L/XL"
        },
        2:  {
            name: "Pant Size",
            value: "30x30"
        },
        3:  {
            name: "Right or Left Handed?",
            value: "Right"
        },
        4:  {
            name: "Shirt Size",
            value: "M"
        },
        5:  {
            name: "Shoe Size",
            value: "9"
        },
        6:  {
            name: "shipping_interval_frequency",
            value: "1"
        },
        7:  {
            name: "shipping_interval_unit_type",
            value: "Months"
        },
        8:  {
            name: "subscription_id",
            value: "1522"
        },
        product_exists: true,
        fulfillable_quantity: 1,
        total_discount: "0.00",
        tax_lines: [0]
      }
   }
};
```

This is valid javascript object but not JSON object.

To be a valid JSON you need keys to be strings ( "key":value )

```
{
"orders": [50],
"0":{
    "name": "#1347",
    "line_items": [1],
    "0":{
        "fulfillment_service": "manual",
        "fulfillment_status": null,
        "gift_card": false,
        "grams": 0,
        "id": 966685828,
        "price": "45.00",
        "product_id": 455951420,
        "quantity": 1,
        "requires_shipping": true,
        "sku": "",
        "taxable": true,
        "title": "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)",
        "variant_id": 1292559264,
        "variant_title": "",
        "vendor": null,
        "name": "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)",
        "variant_inventory_management": null,
        "properties": [9],
        "0":  {
            "name": "Glove Size",
            "value": "M"
        },
        "1":  {
            "name": "Hat Size",
            "value": "L/XL"
        },
        "2":  {
            "name": "Pant Size",
            "value": "30x30"
        },
        "3":  {
            "name": "Right or Left Handed?",
            "value": "Right"
        },
        "4":  {
            "name": "Shirt Size",
            "value": "M"
        },
        "5":  {
            "name": "Shoe Size",
            "value": "9"
        },
        "6":  {
            "name": "shipping_interval_frequency",
            "value": "1"
        },
        "7":  {
            "name": "shipping_interval_unit_type",
            "value": "Months"
        },
        "8":  {
            "name": "subscription_id",
            "value": "1522"
        },
        "product_exists": true,
        "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
        "total_discount": "0.00",
        "tax_lines": [0]
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to extract the properties, once you you have a reference of your object you can access it with Javascript as

```
var myProperties = response["0"]["0"]["properties"];
```

In PHP after you perform a JSON parse on your response, you can access them as a nested associative array.

```
 $myResponse = json_decode($response);
 $myProperties = $response['0']['0']['properties'];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Just amazing how often this same question pops up on SO ... almost daily.

Answer (score 1):

The data format is incorrect. It is missing commas and brackets. Compare with the working code below to find the dependencies.

Once the data is in correct format it is just a matter of using dot and bracket notation to access. Play with the code below to understand better.

Reference:
[Mozilla - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```
  data['0']['0'].title;
```

**Run code snippet to test:**

```html
<html>
<body>
  
  Value:
  <div id="value" style="font-family:monospace;font-size:16px;"></div>
  <p>
  JSON:
  <textarea id="json" style="background-color:aliceblue;padding:0.5em;border:1px black solid;width:100%; height:40em;"></textarea>

  <script type="text/javascript">


    var data = {
      orders: [50],
      0:
      {
        name: "#1347",
        line_items: [1],
        0:
        {
          fulfillment_service: "manual",
          fulfillment_status: null,
          gift_card: false,
          grams: 0,
          id: 966685828,
          price: "45.00",
          product_id: 455951420,
          quantity: 1,
          requires_shipping: true,
          sku: "",
          taxable: true,
          title: "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)",
          variant_id: 1292559264,
          variant_title: "",
          vendor: null,
          name: "Athletic Style Auto renew (ships every 1 Months)",
          variant_inventory_management: null,
          properties: [9],
          0:
          {
            name: "Glove Size",
            value: "M"
          },
          1:
          {
            name: "Hat Size",
            value: "L/XL"
          },
          2:
          {
            name: "Pant Size",
            value: "30x30"
          }
        }
      }
    };
    
    
    document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = data['0']['0'].title;
    
    document.getElementById('json').value = 'json:\n' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ');
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```